# Nagios - getting historical data and automated trending

Tags: nagios, performance-monitoring

I am using Nagios for an energy efficiency project and workload balancing is a crucial aspect of the project. I am interested in how I can retrieve historical data from Nagios (e.g. CPU load for the past 10 minutes, memory usage for a process) and trends (e.g. CPU load increasing, decreasing). I am a beginner in regard to Nagios so any information about this subject would be helpful.

I am not interested in displaying the information in a graphical manner, I would like to use it in a custom application (Does Nagios have an interface -- web-service based or something else -- trough which to extract such data?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nagios doesn't do this out of the box, but there are plugins for it

- [pnp4nagios](http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/start)
- [nagiosgraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nagiosgraph/)

Personally, I think you're using the wrong tool, you'd be better off with [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/)

Comment: cacti does graphing of historical data very well.  nagios is recently getting into this via new plugins, but nagios is mainly for alert notification, not historical trends analysis.

Comment: I'd also use Cacti, but Munin and Ganglia are other options.